# Function returns 0 value even though it has a different number stored in it

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to return a value from a function so that it is displayed in HTML. It returns 0 on the HTML but it returns the correct input value on the alert message inside the function. Here is the code I have:

```
<body>
  <p>Number of bags: </p>
  <input type="number" id="numBagInputId">
  <input type="submit" id="numBagSubmitId" onClick="myFunction()">
  <p>You will need: </p> 
  <p id="bags"></p>
  <p>grams.</p>
            
<script>
   function myFunction() {
    let dryAmount = document.getElementById("numBagInputId").value * 921;
    alert (dryAmount);
    return dryAmount;
}
        
    let bagTotal = myFunction();
    document.getElementById("bags").innerHTML = bagTotal;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The code above returns a 0 value in the <p id"bags"><p/> html, but on the alert(dryAmount) it returns the correct number form the function (i.e. the numBagInputId.value).

Comment: Please see [ask], then put enough HTML in the snippet I created to show your problem.

Comment: Put all new information in your question post, not in comments.

Comment: I guess you're calling the `myFunction` before the user has the chance to write anything in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't defined any event listener methods, `myFunction()` is called first. However, the value 0 is returned because data has not yet been entered into the `<input>` element. To prevent this, I assigned a value to the `value` attribute of the `<input>` element. The event listener method of the `<input>` element is used to update the value within the program.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('numBagInputId');

function myFunction() {
  let dryAmount = inputElement.value * 921;
  console.log(`Result: ${dryAmount}`)
  return dryAmount;
}

function update(){
  let bagTotal = myFunction();
  document.getElementById("bags").innerHTML = bagTotal + " this is the bag total value";
}

inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(){
  update();
});

update();
```

```html
<p>Number of bags: </p>

<!-- The value attribute is assigned a default value. -->
<input type="number" id="numBagInputId" value="10">

<input type="submit" id="numBagSubmitId" onClick="myFunction()">
<p>You will need: </p> 
<p id="bags"></p>
<span>grams</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your script as given in ss.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWBKq.jpg